# URDF for a sphere

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning URDF, when I tried making a sphere;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="myfirst">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="1.0"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="green">
            <color rgba="0 1 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```

All I get is something more like a polyhedra;

[image: image description]

Is there any way to get a better sphere ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12809/urdf-for-a-sphere/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-01-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm also not aware of a way to change the tesselation of the built-in primitives in rviz. Using an external mesh works fine, however. I've used the default sphere you can add in Blender (32 segments, 16 rings) for the image below. I scaled it and set it to smooth shading (and converted to triangles before exporting to .dae to prevent bugs as mentioned [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/3741/smooth-shading-for-environments-in-gazebo)).

Gazebo on the left, rviz on the right:

[image: image description]

/edit: Two versions of a COLLADA sphere are available [here](http://www.sim.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/%7Ekohlbrecher/ros_trac/sphere_mesh/).
One is using 32 segments/16 rings, the other 16 segments/8 rings.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-30**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher Cheerio !

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-30**:
See the updated post above :)

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-30**:
Stefan Kohlbrecher Thank you, kindly do me a favour - can you please send the files across to my email ? arkapravobhaumik at gmail dot com